# Walker class conditional based on parent menu item label or custom css class

Tags: menus, walker

I'm out of my shallow depth here. I'm trying to add html to the end of drop down menus whose parent item is either a specific item label or custom css class that's been added via the WP menu admin.

Any help appreciated. The basics:

```
public function end_lvl( & $output, $depth = 0, $args = null ) {
    parent::end_lvl( $output, $depth, $args );
    if (/* top-level parent item has [specified label] or [specified css class] */){
       $output .= '<div>See how we can help you <a href="#">Find out more</a></div>';
    }
}
```